# Calculating the closest point a line intersects with a circle on a world map?

Tags: circles, intersection-theory

I am working with the world map and trying to figure out an equation to solve:

- Given starting point A which is latitude 51.137933 and longitude -0.267017, I want draw a straight line or head in the direction of bearing 257 degrees.
- Given an ending point B, which is latitude 51.053953 and longitude -0.625003 (the center of the circle), imagine a 10.5 nautical mile radius around it.
- I want the line from point A to go from there to the closest intersection point of the 10.5 nautical mile radius of point B and I want to know what latitude and longitude this position C is.
- In this example the correct answer should output point C as a lat/lng close to 51.12297220241921 -0.37027234945405624 (although this may be 0.1 miles off).

The below diagram may help better explain (although slightly different example, same concept):

[image]

Forgive me, my maths is not so good as I am primarily a software engineer, so please do dumb down the mathematically terms to help me understand.

I have found that there are similar problems where figuring out whether a line intersects a circle is quite common, but I think this one is slightly different in that;

- I am dealing with the world map, so we may have to account for the curvature of the earth.
- I am only interested in the exact position of the first closest (to point A) intersection, not all intersection points or a simple yes / no whether it intersects.
- Finally, the heading the line is drawn must be fixed to 257 degrees, I have seen some formulas which try to just find the best heading as well, but in this case the heading can't change and in some circumstances that means it will never hit the circle too.

I have actually programmed something that solves this problem, but it doesn't use an equation, instead it's quite inefficient as it brute forces the path until it reaches the circle, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217015/how-to-calculate-the-first-point-where-a-line-intersects-a-circle-radius-on-a-ma/76217601#76217601

I realise this is more a math problem so posting my question here.

Comment: At first glance, your code for the "new latitude and longitude" at each step looks like a great-circle calculation, but each step is always in the direction 257 degrees, which is characteristic of a rhumb line. So you get a path which is certainly not a great circle and is not quite a rhumb line either. The first thing to decide is which kind of path you want. If you choose a great circle, there will be a closed-form solution; for a rhumb line I think a "numerical" method is best, but you can do it more efficiently.

Comment: Aha, I didn't even think of that.  What I know for certain is that the line must remain on the desired bearing, e.g. if it is 257, then it should always be 257.  If the great circle calculation involves changing the bearing (e.g. over distance it becomes 258, 259, etc) then it is not suitable and I just need a rhumb line.  When I mentioned great circle, I was more thinking about the radius of the circle that is being drawn from point B may need to factor in curvature?

Comment: There are good equations for rhumb lines that will let you quickly (and more accurately) calculate the position over a long distance without taking many steps. There would still be some trial and error to find the intersection with the circle but it could be much more efficient. Would that help?

Comment: As long as it's more efficient than my solution (moving down the line path at 0.1 mile increments and then measuring the distance from point B every time), then ye I would defo be interested to see what you got.